# Checking if an argument is an instance of two types

Tags: python

I want to accept an argument into my function. This can be of any type, however in the function I want to check if the type is either a `list` or `string`. I thought the easiest way was by doing `isinstance(arg, Union[str, list]` but that gives the error `NameError:  'union' is undefined`.

What's the cleanest way to do this?

Current code

```py
def get_between(ticker, start_date: datetime, end_date: datetime):
    t = type(ticker)
    if isinstance(t, Union[str, list]):
        return True, coinmarketcap.getDataFor(ticker, start_date, end_date)
    else:
        return False, "Ticker is not an instance of str or list."
```

Comment: `NameError:  'union' is undefined` - you have to import the typing module in order to make it work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for `isinstance(ticker, (str, list))`

From the docs:

> A tuple, as in `isinstance(x, (A, B, ...))`, may be given as the target to
> check against. This is equivalent to `isinstance(x, A) or isinstance(x, B) or ...` etc.

Notice that I'm passing the `ticker` object itself instead of the type. If you want to compare types, you'd need to go for `issubclass`